# Как передать в WebClient_OpenReadCompleted экземпляр класса?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

Есть список экземпляров класса ClassName. В этих экземплярах уже есть некая инфа. Ещё там есть строка URI, по которой надо пройти вебклиентом чтобы достать из АПИ дополнительную инфу для каждого экземпляра. Как передать этот экземпляр в _OpenReadCompleted? Я пробовал

```
   void cl_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("In cl_OpenReadCompleted");

        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
        ClassName new1 = sender as ClassName ;
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", new1.IsGroup)); // вот тут NullREferenseException
```

Не могу пока что додуматься как это сделать, помогите)

Comment: > ClassName new1 = sender as ClassName;
sender содержит ссылку на экземпляр WebClient, который сгенерировал событие OpenReadCompleted.
Остается только догадываться, каким образом он связан с ClassName.
Покажи больше кода.

Comment: void GetSourseInfo(News sourse)
        {
            foreach (New s in sourse)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(s.SourseId) > 0)
                {

                    s.UriInfo = string.Format("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get.xml?uid={0}&fields=first_name,last_name,photo_small&access_token={1}", s.SourseId, App.AccessToken);
                }
                else
                {

                    s.SourseId = s.SourseId.Remove(0, 1);
                    s.UriInfo =

Comment: string.Format("https://api.vk.com/method/groups.getById.xml?gid={0}&fields=name,photo_small&access_token={1}", s.SourseId, App.AccessToken);
                }
                var cl = new WebClient();
                cl.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(cl_OpenReadCompleted);
                cl.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(s.UriInfo));               
            }

            
        }
void cl_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
            Sourse src = new Sourse();

Comment: if ((string)xml.Root.Element("user") != null)
            {
                XElement element = xml.Root.Element("user");
                src.FirstName = (string)element.Element("first_name").Value;
                src.LastName = (string)element.Element("last_name").Value;
                if((string)element.Element("photo") != null)
                src.Photo = (string)element.Element("photo").Value;
            }
            if ((string)xml.Root.Element("group") != null)
            {
                XElement element = xml.Root.Element("group");

Comment: src.FirstName = (string)element.Element("name").Value;
                src.LastName = " ";
                src.Photo = (string)element.Element("photo").Value;
            } 
            sourses.Add(src);

Класс New - контейнер с разными данными и о новости(отправитель, ид отправителя, само сообщение). News - лист New наследуемый от ObservableCollection<New>. Sourse - контейнер, которому передается ид отправителя, по ид строится строка запроса, дается запрос, получается ответ, забрасывается в sourse, потом sourse забрасывается в sourses(такой же лист как News).

Comment: Вообщем решилось это созданием списка sourses, в методе выше достается инфа для каждого sourse, потом забрасывем в sourses, когда все прочиталось - тупо циклом перебрасываю данные из одного листа в другой. Работает конечно, но медленно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так и не понял, к каким объектам тебе нужен доступ из обработчика OpenReadCompleted,
но подозреваю, что проблема решается такой лямбдой:

```
cl.OpenReadCompleted +=
    (sender, e) =>
    {
        // делаем что-то с объектами News/New/Source из текущего скопа
    };
```

Comment: Кажется понял, но почему-то не работает(
foreach (New s in NewsList)
{
var cl = new WebClient();
//  cl.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(cl_OpenReadCompleted);
 cl.OpenReadCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(e.Result);
if ((string)xml.Root.Element("user") != null)
{
XElement element = xml.Root.Element("user");
s.SourseFirstName = (string)element.Element("first_name").Value;
s.SourceLastName = (string)element.Element("last_name").Value;
if ((string)element.Element("photo") != null)
s.SourseImage = (string)element.Element("photo").Value;
}

Comment: if ((string)xml.Root.Element("group") != null)
{
XElement element = xml.Root.Element("group");
s.SourseFirstName = (string)element.Element("name").Value;
s.SourceLastName = " ";
s.SourseImage = (string)element.Element("photo").Value;
}
};
cl.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(s.UriInfo));               
} 

доступ есть, но в результате - пусто

Comment: только что проверил, форич работает, MessageBox.Show(s.SourseFirstName) показывает имя каждого автора, после каждой итерации, но в после форича отображается только последний елемент списка. Выходит что форич постоянно пишет в один объект, но я кажется все правильно написал...

Comment: Вероятно, внутрь лямбды попадает ссылка на один и тот же объект. Пофикси так:

var loc_s = s;
cl.OpenReadCompleted +=
    (sender, e) =>
    {
        // вместо s юзаем loc_s
    };

Comment: спасибо, работает)